# If $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix with a repeated eigenvalue $r$, then $\mathrm{e}^{At}=\mathrm{e}^{rt}\left[I+(A-rI)t\right]$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, exponential-function

> If $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix with a repeated eigenvalue $r$, show that  $\mathrm{e}^{At}=\mathrm{e}^{rt}\left[I+(A-rI)t\right]$.

I have already been able to show that if $A$ is an arbitrary $2\times 2$ matrix 
$$
\left(
\begin{array}\\
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array}
\right),
$$
the repeated eigenvalue $r$ must be equal to
$\,r=\dfrac{a+d}{2}$.

From here, my first thought was to take the determinant of the matrix
$$\mathrm{e}^{rt}\left[I+(A-rI)t\right],$$ 
and show that it is equal to $$\det(\mathrm{e}^{At}),$$ but then I started thinking this would be useless since two unequal matrices can have the same determinant.

I've tried directly substituting $r$ into the right-hand side of the equation as well, but with no luck.

---

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to proceed from here?

Answer (score 6):

As $r$ is an eigenvalue of multiplicity 2 of the $2\times 2$ matrix $A$, 
then $A$ does not have any other eigenvalues, and its characteristic polynomial should be
$$
p(x)=(x-r)^2,
$$
and by [Cayley-Hamilton Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) we have that
$(A-rI)^2=0$.

Next observe that
$$
\mathrm{e}^{tA}=\mathrm{e}^{rt}\mathrm{e}^{t{(A-rI)}}=\mathrm{e}^{rt}\sum_{n=0}^\infty
\frac{(A-rI)^n}{n!}=\mathrm{e}^{rt}\sum_{n=0}^1
\frac{(A-rI)^n}{n!}=\mathrm{e}^{rt}\big(I+
(A-rI)\big)
$$

Answer (score 4):

This is much simpler if you observe that what you're trying to prove is invariant under conjugation/similarity.  That is, it suffices to show this for some matrix *similar* to $A$, not necessarily $A$ itself.

Note that if $A$ has a repeated eigenvalue of $r$, then it must be similar either to $\begin{pmatrix}r & 0 \\ 0 & r\end{pmatrix}$ or to $\begin{pmatrix}r & 1 \\ 0 & r\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: But can we always guarantee that there will be a similar matrix to $A$?

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops Well, $A$ is always similar to $A$, so there's that.  But as I said, we know that $A$ is similar to one of the two matrices above.  It's a good exercise to show this directly for $2\times 2$ matrices, but it follows from the Jordan normal form.

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops Similarity is just a convenience anyway; the real point here is that the condition of the problem implies that $(A-rI)^2 = 0$.  This should be an enormous help in actually computing the power series $e^{At}$.

Comment: I tried using $A=PBP^{-1}$ where $B$ is the diagonal matrix with entries $r$, but I'm still not getting the condition to be satisfied.

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops The $P$ and $P^{-1}$ pull entirely out of both sides of the equation.  You only need to verify it when $A$ equals one of the two matrices I mentioned.  If the similarity argument doesn't make sense to you, try my other suggestion: write $A=rI + N$, verify that $N^2=0$, and use this (and power series!) to show that $e^{At} = e^{rt} (I + Nt)$.

Comment: I got it! Thanks for the help. I ended up using the similarity argument.

Answer (score 4):

They key observation is to write the relation as 
$$e^{(A-rI)t}=I+(A-rI)t.
$$
This is clearly true once you notice that $(A-rI)^2=0$. You can prove this using the Jordan form as Slade mentioned: a $2\times2$ matrix with both eigenvalues equal to zero has its square equal to zero.